# Why not get action from proxy.getAction()

Tags: unit-testing, struts2, junit4

this is my code ,i can get proxy from getActionProxy,but i can't get Action.
that's my first time test Struts2 action and don't know error.
The TestCase ClaimActionTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase.

```
@Test
public void testPrepareAddClaim() throws Exception{
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/claim.action/prepareAddClaim.do");
    System.out.println(proxy.getActionName());
    System.out.println(proxy.getNamespace());
    System.out.println(proxy.getAction());

    ClaimAction action = (ClaimAction) proxy.getAction();

    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    paramMap.put("registNo", "34244432432");
    ActionContext actionContext = proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext();
    actionContext.setParameters(paramMap);

    String result = proxy.execute();
    assertEquals("success", result);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *can't get Action*?

Comment: Are you able to `getActionMapping`?

Comment: I able to getActionMapping,        ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping("/claim/prepareAddClaim.do"); it's test success,but if  getActionProxy("/claim/prepareAddClaim.do") return nullpointException.

Comment: So,I able to getActionProxy("/claim.action/prepareAddClaim.do");

Comment: It;s the printout: prepareAddClaim  |   
/claim.action |
  com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@104dd40

Comment: So problem is solved? It is working?